# How to convert a cURL command to Angular?

Tags: angularjs, curl, oauth

I want this cURL

```
curl https://api.cardinity.com/v1/payments\
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="<your_consumer_key>", \
      oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", \
      oauth_timestamp="<timestamp>", \
      oauth_nonce="<unique_random_string>", \
      oauth_version="1.0", \
      oauth_signature="<computed_oauth_signature>"'
```

transformed into Angular, I've tried everything.

Comment: what do you mean by : transform into angular???
I think you can just make a http request from angular if I didn't get the question wrong. If not so, please explain a little more

Comment: Yes i want to make http request. I've already tried to make headers and so on,  ive tried to make authorization header as a single string, also as an object. When i do it through terminal everything is ok, but i cant make it work through angular

Comment: what errors you are getting when hitting the url angular way

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.cardinity.com/v1/payments. Invalid HTTP status code 401

Comment: Try enabling cors on server side.

Comment: Are you sure it might be server side? because i can make request trough terminal

Comment: put angular code here which you are using to make http request. 
I am just making a guess that if curl hit is working through and angular code is right, you must be making cross domain request. In case of cross domain request, you have to enable cors on server side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: Convert curl to Angular $http POST request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924573/angular-convert-curl-to-angular-http-post-request)